# Compare two dictionaries c# and get the same keys

Tags: c#, dictionary, cpu-word

I have two Dictionaries. One is an actual dictionary (word for key and definition for value) and the other is words that are in a Word File and stored in a seconde dictionary.

```
//first dictionary
    var xdoc = XDocument.Load("dicoFrancais.xml");
            var dico = xdoc.Root.Elements()
                               .ToDictionary(a => (string)a.Attribute("nom"),
                                             a => (string)a.Element("DEFINITION"));

//second dictionary
Dictionary<string, string> motRap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Document document = application.Documents.Open("monfichiertxt.docx");


        int count = document.Words.Count;
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {                
            string text = document.Words[i].Text;                
            motRap.Add(text, "blabla");                
        }
        // Close word.
        application.Quit();
```

And I want to compare the keys of the two dictionaries and get the same keys with the values of the first dictionary, so i can have a third dictionary with that keys and values. 
i tried this : 
`var intersectMembers = dico.Keys.Intersect(motRap.Keys)
                                   .ToDictionary(t => t, t => dico[t]);`
but it doesn't work. 
Can someone help me please,
Thank you. (Sorry my english is not very good)

Comment: "but it doesn't work" What does that mean? What results did you get and what did you expect?

Comment: The third dictionary didn't display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to compare the keys of the two dictionaries and get the same keys with the values of the first dictionary.

```
var thirdDictionary = dico
  .Where(keyValue => motRap.Keys.Contains(keyValue.Key))
  .ToDictionary(keyValue => keyValue.Key, keyValue => keyValue.Value);
```